# Alternate Word Choice

Tags: creative-writing, word-choice

I am currently writing a story for fun and was looking for some advice on a scene. The scene involves two lovers having an exchange that goes something like this:

> Character A smiles warmly. "You know, you're really a very kind person."

> "Lies*." Character B immediately responds, voice deadpan. He flips a page from his book casually. "I save your life and here you are trying to ruin my reputation?" Despite his words, Character A could see his lips quirk a bit.

The exchange works as is, but I feel like there's a synonym for 'lies' that fits better. I tried Google but the closest I could find was 'slander' and although I could use that I was looking for something a bit more...harsh? A word that not only implies defamation but also that the idea goes against the natural order.

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to have verbed the noun *quirk*. to my mind that goes against the natural order!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're looking for a harsh word for lies and don't mind getting into the realm of, well, harsher language than deemed fit for polite company, there's the option to say "bullshit".

Answer (score 0):

Balderdash!

Hogwash!

An insufferable insult!

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Divizna, "Bullshit" or "Bull" for a PG version.

I don't understand why a single word is required.

"How dare you!"

Or,

"Do not repeat that! I just saved you, don't force me to kill you. I have a reputation to protect."

Or,

"More of an investor. You owe me a favor."